# Spring Eureka does not see service instances

Tags: java, spring, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have created microservices application which contains 3 services: chat-ws, users-ws and discovery-service. I want to make a inner http call from one service to another (from chat-ws to users-ws). Here is the method I use to make a http request and also to log.info() instances by id "USERS-WS".

```
public void getUsersData(List<String> userIds){
        List<InstanceInfo>instance = discoveryClient.getInstancesById("USERS-WS");
        log.info("instances --> " + instance);

        String url = "http://users-ws/api/user/usersdata";
        String json = toJson(userIds);
        log.info("json --> " + json);
        Mono<String> response = webClient
                .post()
                .uri(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(json))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);

        response.subscribe(
                responseBody ->{
                    log.info("response body --> " + responseBody);
                },
                error -> {
                    log.warn("error --> " + error);
                }
        );

    }
```

List of instances is empty i doesn't matter if i pass "users-ws" or "USERS-WS", WebClient returns error:

```
[id: 0xd2582735] RECEIVED: UDP [55785: /192.168.2.1:53], DatagramDnsResponse(from: /192.168.2.1:53, to: /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:61795, id: 55785, QUERY(0), NXDomain(3), RD RA)
[ctor-http-nio-1] io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext    : [id: 0xd2582735] WRITE: UDP, [47691: /192.168.2.1:53], DefaultDnsQuestion(users-ws. IN CNAME)
[ctor-http-nio-1] io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver    : [id: 0xd2582735] RECEIVED: UDP [47691: /192.168.2.1:53], DatagramDnsResponse(from: /192.168.2.1:53, to: /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:61795, id: 47691, QUERY(0), NXDomain(3), RD RA)
error --> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'users-ws' [A(1)] after 2 queries
```

So it seems that services are invisible, but under the UI Web interface of spring eureka dashboard they are registered, applications are named "USERS-WS" and "CHAT-WS" they are up and running. Both of this application have EnableDiscoveryClient annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ChatServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChatServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class UserServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Discover-service has @EnableEurkeServer annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here i also present application.properties files of discovery-service

```
server.port=8086
spring.application.name=discoveryservice
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost


eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=DEBUG
```

application.properties of chat-service

```
server.port=${PORT:0}

spring.application.name=chat-ws
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8086/eureka
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.enabled=true

gateway.ip=192.168.2.184

logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

application.properties of user-service

```
server.port=${PORT:0}

spring.application.name=users-ws
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8086/eureka
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.enabled=true

gateway.ip=192.168.2.184
```

Comment: Did you create an `@LoadBalanced` `WebClient`?

Comment: No I didn't but i decided to configure it to be a LoadBalanced client now and it seems to work, thank you very much ! But i still don't uderstand why discoveryClient.getInstancesById() is returning empty list.

Comment: What happens if you use `getServices` instead and use the `getInstances` which takes a service name instead of id. Which `DiscoveryClient` is being used, as when looking at recent versions of that API the method you are using isn't part of the API.

Comment: Thank you very much for directing me to solve the problem. The problem was I used wrong interface, I used EurekaClient interface instead of DiscoveryClient. Now everything works perfectly fine.